# Derive Arc Length formula

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm having trouble deriving the arc length formula. The formula for polar coordinates is $\frac{dl}{d \beta} = \sqrt{r^2 + \frac{dr}{d \beta}^2}$. For further calculations I need $\frac{dl}{d \beta d\alpha}$. $r$ is the radius of an ellipse in polar coordinates ($r = \frac{ab}{ \sqrt{a^2sin(\beta)^2+b^2cos(\beta)^2}}$). $\beta$ is a function of $\alpha$

So far I did this: $\frac{dl}{d \beta d\alpha} = \frac {d \beta }{d\alpha} \frac {\frac{dr}{d \beta} \frac{d^2r}{d \beta^2}+r\frac{dr}{d \beta}}{\sqrt{r^2 + \frac{dr}{d \beta}}}$

However, this does not seem to be correct.

Edit: I know $\frac{d\beta}{d\alpha}$.

Comment: Your formula for arc length in polars is wrong. Please see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArcLength.html

Comment: Your're right. I made a typo. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{dl}{d\beta d\alpha}$ doesn't make sense to me, it's either a concept I've never seen before or you're looking for either $\frac{dl}{d\alpha}$ or $\frac{dl^2}{d\beta d\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have

$$l=\int \sqrt{r^2 + \frac{dr}{d \beta}^2}~d\beta$$

and you wish to find $dl/d\alpha$. So I would suggest that

$$\frac{dl}{d\alpha}=\frac{dl}{d\beta}\frac{d\beta}{d\alpha}=\frac{d\beta}{d\alpha}\sqrt{r^2 + \frac{dr}{d \beta}^2}$$